# XBAP Clear cache from application

Tags: wpf, caching, xbap, mage

Is there a way to clear the cache from Xbap application instead of running mage or rundll32 from command prompt??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know the only available tool is 'mage -cc'.

http://www.vistax64.com/avalon/11917-xbap-applciation-issues.html

Answer (score 2):

Programmaticaly you can use this:

```
new System.Deployment.Application.DeploymentServiceCom().CleanOnlineAppCache();
```

[original](http://newyear2006.wordpress.com/2006/08/10/clickonce-applicationcache-oder-xbap-cache-loschen/)

Don't forget about your app rights.