# Modify .xap file before silverlight ie plugin loads it

Tags: c#, c++, silverlight, debugging, visual-c++

Q1) How to get notified about the .xap file has started downloading and finished?

Q2) Are there any specific api's that start loading the xap file inside the ie environment?

References to programming examples are welcome.

I need the information to make text translation possible within silverlight application.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Answer 1 : There is no such event to check if application is downloaded or not. It depends on browser and network speed.
Its treated as simple file to the browser. Someone asked this question before also
[How do browsers handle caching of XAP packages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6344496/how-do-browsers-handle-caching-of-xap-packages)

Answer 2: Nopes there is no specific API, its browser which does the download and treat it as a file

What type of translation you are looking for?
Localisation?
Probably try out WebService API to do wonders.