# HyperlinkButton in Silverlight points to old URI

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-5.0

I'm new in Silverlight. A used the SilverLight Business Application template to create an application. I added a HypperlinkButton to the MainPain.xaml that pointed to a view, say **ProductListView**. Now I created a new view, say **DataFormView**,  and I wanted the HyperlinkButton to point to that new view in order to test it, but when i run the application, it's the old view that's shown (ProductListView), though i have change the NavigateUri property to point to the new view.
I added a new HyperlinkButton to point to the new view, but it seems that it's the old main page that is shown (with one hyperlink button).

Can anyone help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to know navigation in silverlight, Just open new Silverlight Navigation Application project, where you have simple navigation is performed using navigation frame and Hyperlinkbutton.

Comment: Yes, but why is it that when I make changes to my MainPage.xaml, it is the old version that is shown when I run the application? In design mode i do have the changes, but when i run it, it's the old version

Comment: can you post your code. Most probably the old view is default. I can help you looking at your code.

Answer (score 0):

This is likely a problem with the xap file getting cached. Try rebuilding the application. There are other ways to clear the browser cache as well:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/143414/Prevent-your-Silverlight-XAP-File-from-Caching-in

[Making the Silverlight XAP file expire from browser cache programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2281919/making-the-silverlight-xap-file-expire-from-browser-cache-programmatically)

Comment: I ran VS as Admin and it's Ok. Thanks all!