# How to force visual studio web deploy to publish the latest xap

Tags: visual-studio, silverlight, webdeploy

When I debug my website\silverlight, it will always serve me the latest silverlight app I'm working on. but when I use the built-in web deploy. it won't deploy the latest silverlight xap.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/6129804/34461 as it's the most efficient way.

Answer (score 0):

I've been fighting with this annoyance for days now. and here is the workaround I found:

1. Although this is not much related to the topic, it's a good start point when you face such problem. Make sure your clients download the latest version by marking the xap file path with a query string:`<param name="source" value="@Url.Content("~/ClientBin/YourSilverlightApp.xap")?@DateTime.Now.Ticks" />`

   2. Print the assembly version of your silverlight somewhere on the UI so you can actually confirm it is the latest you had in your debug environment.
   3. Delete the xap from your website folder **and your website project** ClientBin folder.
   4. Rebuild the website and it should create a new xap in your website project.
   5. Now you can publish the entire website or just the xap itself and it should be the latest version.