# How can I refresh the browser page from within a Silverlight app?

Tags: silverlight, browser, refresh

Is there a way to reload the browser page from within Silverlight? i.e. have the same effect as a user clicking the reload button?

Comment: I prefer adding parameter to url query: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1722615/forcing-browsers-to-reload-silverlight-xap-after-an-update

Answer (score 14):

I've always used:

namespace for refresh page :

using System.Windows.Browser;

code:
give this code inside ur button click..

```
HtmlPage.Document.Submit();
```

Comment: Didn't work for me... :(  Silverlight 4.0 on Windows7 x64 on either IE9 or Chrome 24

Answer (score 7):

You could try this::-

```
 HtmlPage.Window.Navigate(HtmlPage.Document.DocumentUri);
```

Comment: @Travis: That might be related to caching so modifying the cache headers sent by the server might help.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. You can use the [NavigationService.Refresh](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.navigation.navigationservice.refresh%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) method to reload the page.

Comment: Does this really reload the browser page? Doesn't sound like it does from the documented link.

Answer (score 2):

http://www.divelements.com/silverlight/tools.aspx

Refer to the link above.

Use:

```
htmlHost.Document.Submit();
```

Answer (score 0):

I use

```
System.Windows.Browser.HtmlPage.Document.Submit();
```

Answer (score 0):

In the html or aspx page hosting your silverlight xap file write this function in javascript

```
function refreshPage() {
   window.location.href = window.location.href + "?updated";
}
```

From inside your silverlight app, write the below piece of code to refresh the app without giving the user and impression that the page refreshed (considering the xap file is cached and it refreshes right away)

```
HtmlPage.Window.Invoke("refreshPage");
```