# Force refreshing Silverlight Application Storage

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, silverlight, caching

I have just deployed a new Silverlight application to several hundred customers. However, many are reporting the same problem - the app looks the same as before - despite massive updates. I've tracked this down to being caused by the Application Storate being stored locally and told my customers to clear this, which inevitably solves their problem.

How can I fix this in future versions ?

I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1722615/forcing-browsers-to-reload-silverlight-xap-after-an-update) thread on SO which indicates a similar problem, though I don't believe it is the same. I have edited my index.aspx file to have

```
string strSourceFile = @"ClientBin/MyApp.MyApp.SL.xap?ver=1.2"
```

rather than

```
string strSourceFile = @"ClientBin/MyApp.MyApp.SL.xap"
```

As far as I can tell, there is no way to tell if this change has fixed my problem without deploying again - which I would like to avoid!

How can I test if this has worked/Will this fix my problem?

Thanks very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out not to be an issue related to the XAP file, but completely unrelated. It is due to a plugin in use in my SL project - Telerik. I have added serialization tags to new RadPane elements in the xaml file. This does not update correctly in Telerik, the radpanes are maintained in the isolated storage. I have posted a new question with this issue here : [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12393006/setting-the-panegroup-of-a-radpane-in-the-codebehind)