# Setting the PaneGroup of a RadPane in the codebehind?

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, telerik, code-behind

I had created a pane group with rad panes in my XAML as follows :

```
       <telerik:RadSplitContainer InitialPosition="DockedBottom" telerik:RadDocking.SerializationTag="RaddySplit">
              <telerik:RadPaneGroup telerik:RadDocking.SerializationTag="PaneGroup">
                 <telerik:RadPane Header="WW2 Adventure" telerik:RadDocking.SerializationTag="WW2">
                        <vws:ww2gamegrid  />
                 </telerik:RadPane>
                <telerik:RadPane Header="WW1 Adventure" telerik:RadDocking.SerializationTag="WW1">
                           <vws:ww1gamegrid  />
                </telerik:RadPane>
             </telerik:RadPaneGroup>
            </telerik:RadSplitContainer>
```

This has a problem however, there is a bug in the telerik RadDocking Serialization, such that when you deploy a site with an additional tab, the number of tabs is maintained in the client's browsers isolated storage.

So, when I try and deploy my new Silverlight page, with "`WW3gamegrid`" added in (another `RadPane`) the user is still returned the same code as above.

Having googled this a bit, it seems as if adding this in the code behind could solve my problem. With that in mind, how can I add a `RadPane` to this `RadPaneGroup` in my `.xaml.cs` code behind?

Any other solutions to the problem would of course, be gladly listened to :)

Thanks very much.

The code I have in the code behind is stolen from another website, and not fully implemented as I don't understand it. I have put it in the constructor for the xaml.cs file

:

```
InitializeComponent();

 RadPane pane = new RadPane();
 pane.Title = "Pane2";
 pane.Header = "Pane2";
 pane.CanUserClose = false;
 pane.CanDockInDocumentHost = false;
 pane.Content = new Button() { Content = "button2" };
 pane.Tag = "tag";
 pane.PaneGroup();
 RadDocking.SetSerializationTag(pane, "abc");
```

How can I make this equivalent to my xaml above, essentially?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To add a RadPane to a RadPaneGroup just use the `AddItem` method (see [Telerik documentation](http://www.telerik.com/help/silverlight/m_telerik_windows_controls_radpanegroup_additem_1.html)).

```
RadPaneGroup paneGroup = new RadPaneGroup();

RadPane pane = new RadPane();
pane.Header = "WW1 Adventure";
pane.Content = new ww1gamegrid();
paneGroup.AddItem(pane, Telerik.Windows.Controls.Docking.DockPosition.Center);
```