# How to force silverlight application to re-download if new version is available on server to prevent any operation on old application by any User

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

I know silverlight is outdated and Microsoft it self has shutdown further development on it. However I came across one strange & security issue.

Understand the following scenario:  I have my silverlight application up & running on hosted server and there are approx 500 user who are using it same time with application version around **192.3XXXX**.

Later on I have developed some crucial business functionality and released application on server with version around **192.4XXXX**. Next day all 500 user are working on application version **192.4XXXX**. and on same day I found that I have made some serious mistake & I have to fix it as soon as possible. so I have applied the fix and released the Application on server with version around 192.5XXXX.

Now here come my Question. How can I enforce this 500 user to use **192.5XXXX** at same time. I can not tell each user to reload the app and some of may misuse the application's functionality (as earlier mention, some serious mistake I made in code like showing confrontational data on some form etc. )

How to overcome such situation? Or something like that I can manage from server to force client reload app and download new version.

Comment: Is the application just running in the browser or also out of browser? If it is just in the browser, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/1722656/1244910

Comment: It's running in browser only. I think your not getting my question. I need some trick to reload new application from server from application itselft.

Comment: Ah, so you want to reload while the application is running. The only thing I can imagine is periodically checking the webserver (text file with version for example) for new versions and forcing a reload with `HtmlPage.Document.Submit()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank Your All,

I came up with wonderful solution. I have created one signalR hub and I am broadcasting the message to all connected client to reload the application.
Let me know if anyone want detail description.